# what does "__workq_kernreturn" indicate in an iOS crash log or when you pause execution of an app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, unix

When debugging on iOS, if I pause execution I often see multiple references to "__workq_kernreturn".

If my app happens to crash, I often see multiple threads identified as below:

```
Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x332d0cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x332d0cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x332d0cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
```

Does "__workq_kernreturn" indicate a thread that is waiting to exit, or a thread that is deadlocked? Is this something to be worried about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's nothing to worry about unless there are lots of them. If there are lots, that suggests you may be spawning more threads than you probably should, but the `workq_kernreturn` is still not a problem itself. It usually means that the thread is finishing. The source for it is available at [opensource.apple.com](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.24.8/bsd/kern/pthread_synch.c) if you want to take a look at what it does.

The most common stack you're probably looking at is this one:

```
_workq_kernreturn
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

Because of optimizations, you don't see the call to [_pthread_workq_return()](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-763.12/pthreads/pthread.c) in there, but that's what's actually happening. `_workq_kernreturn` is just waiting for for the spinlock to finish so it can run the next thing on its queue (or exit).

Comment: The response I received from an Apple engineer on the devforums was "Ignore them. Those are GCD dispatch worker threads that are waiting for work. They may be assigned work to do later, or they may exit if they stay idle long enough."

Comment: I see this same stack trace, but it's the crashing thread.  That's why I'm concerned.  It seems out of my code that is actually crashing.